# How to retrieve params submitted to airflow dag run (retrieve the json provided during the rest call)

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

when triggering airflow via REST interface a json with the dag run parameters is provided.
How can i retrieve the json passed to the dag when triggering it?

Example
Having triggered a dag:

```
curl -X POST https://<airflow-url>/api/experimental/dags/<dag id>/dag_runs -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{<some params encoded as json which I want to later retrieve>}'
```

I want to later retrieve the params encoded in the json via UI or via CLI.

Usecase: you locate a run that succeded and want to reproduce it.

Thanks in advance.

### Heading